# How can I build a scrollable, colored syslog viewer with less, ccze, grep?

Tags: log, grep, less

I'd like to view logfiles with colored output, scrollable and searchable. How do I do that?

I tried `less /var/log/syslog | ccze | grep error`, but it is not scrollable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're doing it the wrong way around. It's `less` that is scrollable so that needs to be the last command in the pipeline:

```
grep error /var/log/syslog | ccze -A | less -R
```

The options used are:

> -A, --raw-ansi
>
> If one wants to enable raw ANSI color sequences instead of using
>        curses, this option does just that.

This makes `ccze` use [ANSI color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) instead of [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29). While `less` can deal with ANSI escapes with the `-R` option (see below), curses are more of a problem. Using the `-A` option of `ccze` neatly sidesteps that issue.

> -R or --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS
>             Like -r, but only ANSI "color" escape sequences are output in "raw" form.  Unlike -r, the screen appearance is maintained
>   correctly in most  cases.
>             ANSI "color" escape sequences are sequences of the form:
>
> ESC [ ... m
>
> where  the  "..." is zero or more color specification characters For the purpose of keeping track of screen appearance, ANSI
>   color escape sequences
>             are assumed to not move the cursor.  You can make less think that characters other than "m" can end ANSI color  escape  sequences 
>   by  setting  the
>             environment variable LESSANSIENDCHARS to the list of characters which can end a color escape sequence.  And you can make
>   less think that characters
>             other than the standard ones may appear between the ESC and the m by setting the environment variable LESSANSIMIDCHARS to the 
>   list  of  characters
>             which can appear.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Even worse, it freezes my terminal while giving random character output.

Comment: @user430 ah, yes, sorry. The `less` command needs the `-R` flag in order to interpret the color codes correctly. Also, `ccze` apparently uses ncruses output by default so you also need `-A` to disable that. Try the updated answer.